# How to get page number in footer with the prefix "S" with LaTex?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

Could you help to comment how to get page number in footer with the prefix "S" ? I could not find examples in LaTex by searching... Many thanks for your time and help !

Comment: `\renewcommand\thepage{S\arabic{page}}`

Comment: Is there a chance you'll need to cross-reference page numbers? If so, will it be the case that you would *not* have the letter `S` appear in the cross-reference?

Comment: Have you taken a look for the [fancyhdr package](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf)

Comment: @Skillmon - The problem with redefining \thepage is that it is used everywhere, like the table of contents and \pageref.

Comment: @JohnKormylo since OP did not specify the scope of the change clearly I posted the easiest way to achieve it, though I admit that the side effects are huge. The question in Mico's comment was not answered so I don't see a way to correctly answer OPs question. So my comment stays a valid solution, it might be a poor solution, but it could as well be exactly what OP wants. I can't know with the current amount of information.

Comment: @Skillmon - Yeah.  After I made that comment I started thinking that changing everything could be precisely what was wanted.